# How to deal with cases where a proven answer does not work for the OP?

Tags: discussion, support

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860207/change-background-color-of-active-button/35860298?noredirect=1#comment59385598_35860298) we gave the answer to the OP's question, which is working fine in the snippet and fiddle.

But the OP says that when they copy that answer from StackOverflow to their local project it doesn't work.

How to handle/deal with this type of problems? What should/can we do for this type of questions?

Should we just leave it alone?

Comment: Not much. The problem is elsewhere, and if the question has been substantially answered (as is the case here) then there's not much recourse for the OP either.

Comment: @BoltClock So, we should leave it as it idle. Without any activity.

Comment: I think you can vote to close the question with the "Questions seeking debugging help must include the code within the question itself" close reason, because in that case the code that is currently provided in the question doesn't reflect the actual problem and answers will be addressing a different problem altogether.

Comment: You could ask the op to update their question with their more recent attempts (which you have). For what its worth, its not a good idea having two of the same attribute in an html tag, your answer breaks if you put the other class attribute first

Comment: @Sayse I have already ask for that in comment. But, he didn't reply.

Comment: Just move on for the time being, if the op wishes to work with you to find a solution then they will reply

Comment: @all My intention is not downvote the op question. As OP question format is good and enough information to identify the issue and clear question. I think no need to downvote on question. My gentle request is if question  looks ok then then don't downvote.

Comment: 'doesn't work' with no additional debug info, (that may well be specific to their environment), - DCV, everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: Been there. Last week I spent 4 hours debugging a project, helping with all little things and in the end one of the little things didn't work for him and he left my answer unnaccepted. Just ignore such questions or close them.

Comment: Closing is not accurate. Downvote if you don't like the question. The provided close reason in the comments are crap and most of the times they do not reflect the actual problem in the question.

Comment: PLEASE STOP ABUSING about closing questions. I understand you guys love to close questions but lately the close reasons are crap and there has been an abuse of reasons like "too broad" that do not reflect the actual question problem but rather a dumb best-fit even when every possible fit is not actually a fit. CLOSING a question should orient the OP in the way the question should be modified to be reopened, and most of the times the OP is not asking about how to debug de code, but instead help with the actual problem. Don't like the question? Downvote. Stop closing by bulls***

Comment: One thing nobody's mentioned yet is that in many such situations the OP is facing an XY Problem. They _think_ they know what they need but their real problem is completely different.  The canonical example is people who've recently been introduced to regular expressions and now think they are the solution to all their problems.  The biggest part of helping these people is figuring out what they _really_ need.  If, after some prompting, they steadfastly cling to their view I gently back away and go about my business.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I've spent a total of about ten years on the "answering side" of various tech help sites and if there's one thing I've learned is that there's a small group of people who are just not able to solve problems on their own. At all.

Don't misunderstand me, I'm not one of those "zomg all the stooooopid noobz!!1!" curmudgeons, and have quite a bit of understanding for people struggling even with "simple" and "obvious" problems. I still have my first programming book from almost twenty ago with confused notes because I didn't understand how a (C-style) `for` loop worked. So there.

But some people aren't just confused. They seem to be completely lacking the ability to solve problems on their own. They will (try to) follow instructions you give them to the best of their ability, and once it fails, they simply come back with "doesn't work". Usually without a descriptive message. They don't try to use the information you gave them to try and fix the problem on their own. In Dutch we call this "not looking beyond the length of your nose".

These people are a somewhat rare breed, and they're probably distinct from the [help vampire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/166789) breed in that they really do seem to try (or at least want to try); although it's also possible that they're the same species after all. Anthropologists smarter than me can decide.

Why are these people the way they are? I don't know. I'm not in the habit of passing judgement on others over the internet (or at all, for that matter). Perhaps this person is eleven years old, perhaps this person just doesn't understand English well enough, or perhaps, let's be honest here, this person just doesn't have any aptitude for this. Perhaps something else.

I once had a prolonged year-long encounter with a member of this species from Afghanistan who had very poor English skills, was in a job he didn't like but was forced to keep due to awkward personal circumstances, with co-workers who  were bullying him. It's not easy to creatively fix problems in such circumstances. (The basic idea is that people have a limited "[mental bandwidth](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/aug/23/scarcity-sendhil-mullainathan-eldar-shafir)" and can only worry about so many problems at once; [this is also substantiated by research](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/economics/staff/amani/mani_science_976.full.pdf)).

At any rate, there are two things you can do:

1. Move on.
2. Set patience to the MAX and try to help this person.

Your choice. Both are fine. You have no obligation *whatsoever* to help people here. If your answer doesn't work for the OP then that's fine. Doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: 'These people are a somewhat rare breed' - not on SO, they're not.

Comment: @MartinJames I've seen comparatively few people who are truly *unable* to solve problems on their own. Sure, there are the "help vampires" and "somewhat clueless", but this is not really the same thing; the help vampires often just don't care, and the clueless often just need ... some clues.

Comment: Meh - it's not possible to tell them apart without an extra, external reference.  It's like gravity and linear acceleration.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker There are *lots* of people that are just unable to get the work done on their own.  The difference is most of them drop out of school fairly quickly, and can't get a job or keep one for long, so you tend to not interact with them in a professional context all that often.

Comment: @Servy One of the reasons I worry about the people who are quick to answer these kinds of questions is that the people Carpetsmoker speaks of get and keep a job, basically due to SO... :(

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan [Yeah, that worries me as well sometimes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WGsG2.jpg). But it's hardly a new development. Those people existed (and still exist) on forums and maillists as well. Although arguably Stack Overflow has made the problem worse because it works *better* at getting good answers.

Comment: You better believe I read curmudgeons as cumdragons.

Comment: Good lord son! Don't Google such things. I don't know how you could flip that to say _anything_ about you.

Comment: Your answer is more of a description of the problem - a comment to the main question, not a solution [even though you provide two things we could do]. In the case of a correct answer, any help other than a more detailed description of the answer would be answering a separate question. I think Sobrique's answer goes well with the spirit of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 18):

Provided I'm at least reasonably confident that my solution is "correct" (it runs, produces the desired output) then as far as I'm concerned "it doesn't work" is a separate question, and I encourage the supplicant to ask it separately.

By all means include a reference to the current question, but also include all the things needed to make it a 'proper' question:

- The code you're running
- the problem you're having
- error messages/related environmental factors

etc.

And in this way, I can leave my (correct) solution to the question for future reference, and proceed with trying to grok the *other* problem of 'why does this code not run in this user's environment' - which is usually a completely different problem.

Comment: This appears to be a  directly useful answer wrt the answerer - they get credit in posterity for a good answer by readers -  and the asker  -they can provide the requisite details on the second question. If the asker does not follow up they may simply have disappeared / forgotten.